# git clone репозитория с сабмодулями, непоследовательный запрос логина-пароля

Tags: git, git-clone

При выполнении git clone URL для Git-репозитория с сабмодулями возникает проблема - приглашения ввода логина/пароля выводятся одновременно сразу для нескольких репозиториев.

Воспроизведение:

```
user@server:~$ git clone --recursive https://local.gitlab.ru/dev/subsystem.git
Cloning into 'dev_subsystem'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1851, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1851/1851), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (630/630), done.
remote: Total 1851 (delta 1126), reused 1805 (delta 1097), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1851/1851), 14.40 MiB | 13.58 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1126/1126), done.
Submodule 'submodules/submodule-pyramid2' (https://global.gitlab.ru:2443/timteh/submodule-pyramid2.git) registered for path 'submodules/submodule-pyramid2'
Submodule 'submodules/ctrl_v2' (https://local.gitlab.ru/dev/ctrl_v2.git) registered for path 'submodules/ctrl_v2'
Submodule 'submodules/qwerty3' (https://global.gitlab.ru:2443/name/qwerty3.git) registered for path 'submodules/qwerty3'
Submodule 'submodules/systemrd' (https://local.gitlab.ru/imported/systemrd.git) registered for path 'submodules/systemrd'
Cloning into '/home/user/dev_subsystem/submodules/submodule-pyramid2'...
Username for 'https://global.gitlab.ru:2443': 
Username for 'https://global.gitlab.ru:2443': user@local.gitlab.ru
Password for 'https://user@local.gitlab.ru@global.gitlab.ru.ru:2443': 
Password for 'https://my_password@global.gitlab.ru:2443': 
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Как видно, запросы логинов и паролей перемешиваются между собой и в итоге пользователь вводит свой пароль вместо логина.

Для простоты понимания выделил строки авторизации по отдельности, все ссылки и имена заменены.

Пока проблема решена на уровне кэширования лог-пасса, но хотелось бы, чтобы запросы шли последовательно в случае, если лог-пасс пользователя не закэширован.

Comment: Выглядит, как багрепорт, а не вопрос.

Comment: Ну, вопрос тогда такой: как можно исправить эту проблему?

Comment: кардинально? уйти от парольной аутентификации и http-транспорта.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы объяснить чуть подробнее, в чем же все-таки проблема?